# Get URL remove +

Tags: url

My URL
print.html?name=Bentley+Foong&b=1&c=2

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var name = (location.search.split('name=')[1]||'').split('&')[0];
document.getElementById("print_to").innerHTML = name;
</script>
```

Result on my HTML show : Bentley+Foong

How can I remove this "+"

Thank you.

Comment: strings in javascript have `replace` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function to get parameters value from URL

`function __get_parameter_by_name(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}`

Answer (score 0):

You would do a very simple replace

```
var name = (location.search.split('name=')[1]||'').split('&')[0];
name = name.replace("+", " ");
```